# Are there any meaningful differences between the [overlap] and [overlapping] tags?

Tags: discussion, tags

The [overlap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/overlap) tag (1.7k questions) is defined as:

> "Two or more elements overlap when they partially or totally cover one
> another."

While the [overlapping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/overlapping) tag (~850 questions) is defined as:

> The overlapping tag is used to describe elements on a webpage,
> absolutely positioned with CSS so they overlap each other.

Overlapping seems to be specific to CSS positioning, while overlap seems to be horribly generic. Should they be merged? Should either or both be burninated?

Comment: Well, the two tags do overlap quite a lot

Comment: Neither of the tag wikis have any usage guidance. At the very least they should be synonymised.

Comment: Is there any [overlapping] [overlap] between [overlap] and [overlapping]?

Comment: They're both terrible tags regardless of the answer. Outside of CSS, they are utterly meaningless without more context, and they won't mean the same thing in various contexts. Trying to limit them to a CSS context is bad, too, as it's way too narrow a topic to warrant a tag.

Comment: That both tags should be removed.

Comment: @jpmc26 There is also the SQL `OVERLAPS` operator, which *might* warrant a separate tag. A cursory search has around ~350 questions out of the discussed 2.5k.

Comment: @Bergi An operator doesn't warrant a tag. That is far too fine grained a topic to expect people to be following it. Just use [tag:sql].

Comment: "Let's remove the [overlapping] [overlap]"

Comment: @jpmc26 All I'm saying is that there's a well-defined concept of "overlapping" outside of CSS

Comment: @Bergi You are also suggesting that is a sufficient condition to warrant a tag. It is not. Tags should focus on areas of expertise so answerers can follow them.

Comment: @jpmc26 How to write and optimise queries for overlaps in relational databases is an area of expertise.

Comment: Can't [overlap] and [overlapping] be used when questions for creating UI images (in any language) that overlap?

Comment: @Bergi: Sure, *that*'s narrow enough to have a tag, with a name like [sql-overlap] rather than [overlap].  The question becomes whether it's *too* narrow; jmpc26 already argued that it was.  I don't have an opinion on that; IDK whether it makes sense for someone to want to filter their question feed to only see [sql-overlap] questions but not other [sql] questions.  For other purposes (finding *answers*), `[sql] overlap` searches should be fine, with the word "overlap" as free text.

Comment: @Bergi that belongs under SQL. We don't need a tag for every operator or specific expertise, if another tag already covers it pretty competently. You could also use the specific RDBS tag if you are asking about the operator under X server.

Comment: @Braiam I won't argue that we need it, I just disagree that "*Outside of CSS, they are utterly meaningless*" - there is at least one other context where it's meaningful.

Comment: @Bergi yes, but that would be a pretty low bar to clear in that case for a tag to exist. The bar is higher than that.

Answer (score 7):

No, there is no meaningful difference between [overlap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/overlap) and [overlapping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/overlapping) other than grammatically.

It should be burninated, in favor of better tags as described below.

#### Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?

Broadly, it seems the questions mostly deal with the [layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/layout) of elements on a user interface.  There's a specialty within layout considering index (like [z-index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/z-index)) but it seems [layer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/layer) handles most of that specifically.

A minority consider overlapping time periods, specifically the PostgreSQL `OVERLAPS` keyword which is misused here; these questions should have the incorrect tag removed.

### Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?

Only in the sense of a meta-tag, where it is too broad without more specificity.

### Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?

Broadly if the question is dealing with layout layers, but the tags [layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/layout) and [layer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/layer) suffice, and [overlap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/overlap) adds no additional value.

### Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?

As the confusion with overlapping time periods demonstrates, no.